# How to Generate a Stock Summary by period

Tags: laravel

I build a Inventory management system, so i want to generate the Stock Summary, and i want to be sure in this Logic of caluculations.

WE KNOW THAT::

> Closed Balance= Open Balance+ Inward(Purchased)-Outward(issued)

so I have there tables

product table with (`open balance,item_name ......`)

Inward table with (`qty,item_id,date .....`)

Outward table with (`qty,item_id,date .....`)

Example: I want to select `stock summary` from `01/04/2020` up to 30/04/2020, so my question is

i will take open_balance(created once) and select `sum (qty) from Inwards where date between` and `sum (qty) from Outwards where date between`  then i will applied the formula to get the closed balance?? am I right? or there is another logic.

This logic is the way am doing right now am asking is it right or not

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194693/where-to-ask-question-about-logic hello @Emma, I recommend You testing your logic in a table test, then when it is correct try to implement it first with SQL and after that in Laravel.

Comment: I tested on my sql it works fine but, what i need is that correct they way i implemented my logic?